# Put a <a> tag with image one on top of another

Tags: css

Here is the schema I'd like to have https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dXzE.jpg

```
<div class='yellow/brown'>
    <div class='green'>Some sentence</div>
    <div class='blue_wrapper'>
        <a>
            <img src="" class="blue1">
        </a>
        <a>
            <img class="blue2" src="">
        </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Right now the whole set is as **brown**, but I want it to be like **yellow**. Here is the css:

```
.blue_wrapper{
    position: relative; top: 0px; letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.yellow/brown{
    border-bottom: 1px solid blacK;
    padding: 20px;
}

.green{
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.blue1, .blue2{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 1.5vw;
}
```

I've tried this many times but always failed. Does anyone have any idea how? Thank you very much for your help...

Comment: Does a selector like `.yellow/brown` really work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could approach it like this:

```css
.wrap {
    display: table; 
    table-layout: 
    fixed; width: 100%;
}
.images{
    width: 20px;
}
.content, .images {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class='content'>Some sentence</div>
    <div class='images'>
        <a>
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/20/20">
        </a>
        <a>
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/20/20">
        </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want your code to reflect the top image of the two in your link. The code is in the link below. It's rather simple. But I do want to warn you that the `/` operator is not a valid class naming (I forgot the word for that).

```
.green{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.yellow{
    letter-spacing: 0;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    border:2px solid orange;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.blue_wrapper{
    float:left;
}
.blue1{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.blue2{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Here is your [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/XXYaYz)